# Как в Android OpenGL загрузить текстуру в после выполнения onSurfaceCreated?

Tags: android, opengl

В Android OpenGL ES 1.0 у меня загружаются и накладываются на треугольники текстуры, но только если они загружаются в onSurfaceCreated (в классе, имплементирующем GLSurfaceView.Renderer). Если ровно такую же загрузку сделать при отрисовке кадров (при событии прикосновения к экрану), то треугольники отображаются белые без текстур. Текстур слишком много, чтобы загружать их всех сразу в onSurfaceCreated, и они должны выборочно загружаться уже во время работы приложения.